# Banach spaces of continuous functions on $[a,b]$

Tags: vector-spaces, banach-spaces

There is a claim in some lecture notes on ODEs I am using to study that for any closed subset $G \subset \mathbb{R^{d}}$ the space $C([a,b],G)$ with the supremum norm is a Banach space.

The notes do not explicitly state how to interpret the notation, but I think this means that if $f \in C([a,b],G)$, then $f: [a,b] \to G$.

I know that $C([a,b],\mathbb{R^{d}})$ with the supremum norm is a Banach space, but I don't understand why $C([a,b],G)$ is even a vector space. To show that it is a vector subspace of $C([a,b],\mathbb{R^{d}})$ we need to show that it is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication, i.e.
if $f,g \in C([a,b],G)$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$, then $cf+g \in C([a,b],G)$ or in other words that the range of $cf+g$ is in $G$. However, I don't see how to show that given that we only that $G$ is closed (meaning it contains all of its limit points). I am pretty sure that this is false unless $G$ is a subspace.

Am I missing something or do I misunderstand the notation? I could not find anything while googling for examples of Banach spaces. The examples always use $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R^{d}}$ as the codomain.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: I think you're correct (if not, then I'm missing something also), and maybe the person who originally said/wrote this misstated, and only intended to say that it is a complete metric space, which might be all that's needed later.

Comment: Is $G$ supposed to be a subset or a linear subspace?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Nevertheless, you can't define a norm on a metric space.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net The notes only state a subset, maybe they intended to say subspace. Then it would make sense. If we just say subset, then there is no way to show anything regaring addition or scalar multiplication since a set does not have these operations.

Comment: *Nevertheless, you can't define a norm on a metric space.* --- I realize that, and as I said earlier, maybe the author only intended to say it is a complete metric space. Note, for example, that the [Banach fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) (used for differential equations existence and uniqueness results) is a theorem about complete metric spaces.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing that out. The author proceeds by showing the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem, but I don't see where it is relevant that $G$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R^{d}}$ since he never revers to the range of the function specifically. In the proof he constructs a Cauchy sequence in $C([a,b],G)$, so the only thing we need is as you've said a complete metric space. However, after that he proves the Peano existence theorem where we often need addition of functions, so we actually need a normed space here and it must be complete. He also constructs a specific $G$ in the domain $D$ of the ODE.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Actually after giving this another thought I think you might be right that we only need a complete metric space. If $G$ is closed in $\mathbb{R{d}}$, then $C([a,b],G)$ is closed in $C([a,b],\mathbb{R{d}})$ by the definition of the supremum norm if I am not mistaken. So $C([a,b],G)$ is a complete metric space as it is a closed subset of a complete metric space. Is this what you meant?

Comment: I don't know about the specific details, as I haven't examined an ODE existence proof in quite a while, but it seemed like a reasonable guess that some (all?) algebraic structure might not be needed. However, now that I think about it, I don't see the point when studying ODE's in considering functions whose image values are restricted to an arbitrary (but fixed, and presumably nonempty) closed set.

Comment: I will need to go through the proof again, but the author does not require $G$ to be a strict subset. The idea of the proof is to construct approximate solutions which then converge to a solution of the IVP. Of course, it is hard for you to say much without seeing the proof. I just wanted to know if my reasoning why $C ([a,b],G)$ is a complete metric space makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $C([a,b],\mathbb{R^{d}})$ be the vector space of functions $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R^{d}}$ and define the norm $\|f\|_{\infty}=\sup \limits_{x}\|f(x)\|_{2}$, then it can be shown that this is a complete metric space w.r.t the metric induced by the norm.

Now note that $C([a,b],G)$ is a closed subset $C([a,b],\mathbb{R^{d}})$.

Proof:
Let $f$ be a limit point of $C([a,b],G)$ in the metric space $C([a,b],\mathbb{R^{d}})$. This means that $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists$ a function $g_{\epsilon} \in C([a,b],G):g_{\epsilon} \in B_{\epsilon}(f)$, i.e. $\|f-g_{\epsilon}\|_{\infty}=\sup \limits_{x}\|f(x)-g_{\epsilon}(x)\|_{2}<\epsilon$.

This implies $\|f(x)-g_{\epsilon}(x)\|_{2} \leq \sup \limits_{x}\|f(x)-g_{\epsilon}(x)\|_{2}<\epsilon$ $\forall x \in [a,b]$. Then $f(x)$ is a limit point of $G$ in $\mathbb{R^{d}}$ since $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists$ a point $g_{\epsilon}(x) \in G:g_{\epsilon}(x) \in B_{\epsilon}(f(x))$. Since G is closed it contains all its limit points, so that the range of the function $f$ is contained in $G$ and $f \in C([a,b],G)$. It follows that $C([a,b],G)$ contains all its limit points and thus must be closed.

Now it is easy to see that $C([a,b],G)$ is a complete metric space since it is a closed metric subspace of the complete metric space $C([a,b],\mathbb{R^{d}})$.

If we assume that $G$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R^{d}}$, then it is also a Banach space.